# SQL rows sharing same column value and with where

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

[image: TABLE]

For MySQL,
From the given table, I am interested in all rows that have CASE_ID=1510001, but also the rows that share same MESSAGE_ID.

Eg: If CASE_ID=1510001

Output has to be below. The SQL has to take a input CASE_ID. Thank you for the suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM given_table WHERE message_id IN (SELECT message_id FROM given_table WHERE case_id = 1510001);
```

[MySQL subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html)